Variable Response Times in Concurrent API Calls with OpenAI's ChatCompletion API
I'm experiencing variable response times when making concurrent API calls to OpenAI's ChatCompletion API using Python's ThreadPoolExecutor. While I have implemented parallel requests for 3 different prompts, the execution times for the 3 requests vary significantly, with some taking much longer than others, despite all being triggered simultaneously.
For example, the response times are:

2.58 seconds
4.44 seconds
12.00 seconds

Environment

Model : GPT-4o-mini

Tier  : 1

Avg Token Size : I/P = 5000 , O/p = ~300


I'm looking for insights into optimizing these calls for more consistent response times and any strategies for effectively managing concurrent requests to the API.
def main(input_data):

    example_op= input_data['output_format']
    actual_prompt = input_data['prompt']
    text = input_data['text']
    filename = input_data['file_name']


    start = time.time()
    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model='gpt-4o-mini',
        messages = [
                        {'role': "system", "content": SYSTEM},
                        {'role': "user", "content": EXAMPLE_PROMPT},
                        {'role': "assistant", "content": json.dumps(example_op)},
                        {'role': "user", "content": actual_prompt.format(text)}
                    ] ,
        temperature = 0,
        max_tokens = 1000
        
        
    )
    end = time.time()
    print('Time taken : ', end-start)
    return completion

prompts = [
                {"output_format" : EXAMPLE_OUTPUT_EXPERIENCE , "prompt" : ACTUAL_PROMPT_EXPERIENCE, "text" : text, "file_name" : 'filename' },
                {"output_format" : EXAMPLE_OUTPUT_EDUCATION , "prompt" : ACTUAL_PROMPT_EDUCATION, "text" : text, "file_name" : 'filename'},
                {"output_format" : EXAMPLE_OUTPUT_PI , "prompt" : ACTUAL_PROMPT_PI, "text" : text, "file_name" : 'filename'}            ]

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)as executer:
        response = executer.map(main1, prompts)
        res = [i for i in response]

